# Parse, use Cloud Code to only send the first frame of gifs

Tags: android, parse-platform

Currently, I'm downloading a list of ParseObjects that have a URL, which I then use to load gifs over the network into my list items. This is obviously quite slow for a list, and even using Glide and only displaying the first frame, it still takes several seconds to display anything into the view.

What I'd like to do, is write some custom Cloud Code to only send the client the first frame of the gif and use that as a preview to display in the list, then download the actual gif when the preview is clicked on. Obviously I would have to have the gifs uploaded as a ParseFile instead of just a URL but that isnt the issue.

Could this be done? If so, how?